# Unable to recognise number 5

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using Pytesseract to recognize an image for number 5 and I'm stunned that even after applying various filters like GlaussianBlur and Threshold and applying dilation and erosion to remove the noise, it is still not able to identify the image.

Filters Tried:

```
        1: cv2.threshold(cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (9, 9), 0), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1],
        2: cv2.threshold(cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7), 0), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1],
        3: cv2.threshold(cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1],
        4: cv2.threshold(cv2.medianBlur(img, 5), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1],
        5: cv2.threshold(cv2.medianBlur(img, 3), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1],
        6: cv2.adaptiveThreshold(cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0), 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2),
        7: cv2.adaptiveThreshold(cv2.medianBlur(img, 3), 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2),
```

**Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise**

```
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
```

**Training Data:**

eng.traineddata

**Original Image**

[image]

Not sure what is going wrong here, I read the documentation for Tesseract and applied all the pre-processing steps mentioned there. Can someone help where I am going wrong here

Comment: Are you using LSTM version of tesseract? Please add image after preprocessing to your question & current output of tesseract.

Comment: Image posted is post pre-processing image only, Yes I'm using LSTM version.

Answer (score 0):

Try `--psm 10`

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import requests
import io

response = requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcPqGs.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content)), lang='eng',
                config='--psm 10')

print(text)
```

This should yield `5`.